# How can I generate a "Garbage Collector Logs"

Tags: java, garbage-collection

How do I generate a garbage collector log in Java?

Following many guides on the internet, they tell me to modify the command line I use to start Java, by inserting certain flags. Is there any other alternative way to generate it right away?

Is it possible?

I tried to search on the internet, but everyone tells me to insert a certain flag to make it generate the log, but I need to do it immediately. I'm hoping it is possible.

Comment: If you're talking about changing this setting in a running process, I doubt that it's possible. You might be able to change some settings using JMX, but I don't know if you can toggle any particular GC setting.

Comment: a ok close this report thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`DiagnosticCommandMBean`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.management/com/sun/management/DiagnosticCommandMBean.html) to send the same commands to the HotSpot JVM, you can send via [`jcmd`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jcmd.html), except that “VM.log” becomes “vmLog”, etc.

The following code enables logging to stdout

```java
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
 
import javax.management.*;
 
class GcLogExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMException {
 
        String[] command = { "what=gc" };
 
        String result = (String)ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().invoke(
            ObjectName.getInstance("com.sun.management:type=DiagnosticCommand"),
            "vmLog", new Object[] { command },
            new String[] { command.getClass().getName() });
 
        if(!result.isBlank()) System.out.println(result);
 
        for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
            var obj = new int[10_000_000];
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo on Ideone](https://ideone.com/rbREqh)

The following variant enables garbage collection logging into a temporary file:

```java
class GcLogExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMException, IOException {
 
      Path p = Files.createTempFile("gc", ".log");
      System.out.println("GcLogExample.main(): logging to " + p);

      String[] command = { "output=" + p, "what=gc" };
 
      String result = (String)ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().invoke(
          ObjectName.getInstance("com.sun.management:type=DiagnosticCommand"),
          "vmLog", new Object[] { command },
          new String[] { command.getClass().getName() });
 
      if(!result.isBlank()) System.out.println(result);
 
      for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
          var obj = new int[10_000_000];
      }
    }
}
```

You can turn the garbage collector logging off by sending the command `what=gc=off`.